# Do I need to add an ID value to my objects?

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have all these nice objects set up and ready to be added to tables. How are the objects made unique when I say:

```
CREATE TYPE obj_table AS TABLE OF obj_type;
```

Do I need to create a table that pairs an item with an ID, and declare the ID to be the primary key, or is this somehow done implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PL/SQL nested tables (see [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm)), the index number is implicit with the definition of the table and assigned as you insert items into your defined table.